# objects wont follow rotation of the object they are on using Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am Using Geometry Nodes and i want sprinkles to follow the surface of the icing of the cupcake.
i have tried lots of things and cant get it to work.

[image]

They Just point in random directions and want to know why.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...point in random directions and I want to know why

This is mainly due to the fact that you're feeding in the rotation input of the **Instance on Points** node with random degrees of rotation (0 -> 2 pi) which you derived from the **Random Value** node.

> sprinkles to follow the surface of the icing of the cupcake

What you'd want to do differently, in this case, is to get rid of the **Random Value** node and adjust the rotation of the sprinkles only on its local X-axis and Y-axis using the **Rotate Euler** node to get the sprinkle to follow the surface of the icing

The result should look something like this:
[image]

Here's the node setup:

[image]

Comment: Yes This Worked! However would it be possible to rotate the sprinkles to still be on the icing properly whilst being in random directions? Thanks Tho

Comment: Sure, you'd need to find which local axis is the one that's currently pointing outwards from the sprinkles and then rotate your sprinkles around that axis. In this case, that'd be the X-axis. The setup would look like this.https://i.imgur.com/XEPa2Zp.png

Comment: Thanks for the help!